# How to solve Excel memory error: A record that exceeds the max page size of the storage object (65528 bytes)

Tags: excel, powerbi, report, vlookup

Have a document from a previous co-worker. The document is an aggregate of several Excel reports pulled from an SAP application and a media software called Prisma and Mbox. I only know that he used power BI and Vlookups to build this Excel dashboard. It was working fine for 8 months since I have been with the company and was THE person to run it every week. This week I encountered this problem where it says:

> We couldn't get data from Data Model

Here's the error message:

> Memory error: A record (66341 bytes) was encountered that exceeds the maximum page size of the storage object (65528 bytes)

Has anyone run into this error before?

I know nothing about PowerBI and would be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction. Where should I be looking? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a 32 bit installation of Excel? (Memory limited to 2 GB might be the issue) Also, check your open connections. If the old connections are not closed, they might consume the memory.  And finally, if the issue persists, try to apply any potential filters in the data connection query string and/or remove unused columns.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a very specific solution to this problem, but the pattern is similar. I had a file that worked fine for a long time, then suddenly failed with the same error. I spent a lot of time looking into memory issues before I realized that one of the data sources I was importing from an Excel spreadsheet HAD BEEN pulling only the information in the table on that sheet but for some reason started pulling every column on the sheet. They were all empty, but getting pulled into the data model nonetheless and quickly overwhelming it. The solution was to modify the query to make sure it was pulling from the TABLE only, not from the SHEET.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if someone has in the meantime found a better solution to this issue.

We encountered the same issue with a PowerBI dataset which is continuously growing as we include more tables (and therefore columns) to the model. The error seems to be specific to excel and not limited to PowerBI. Apparently the size limitation is on a row / record level where a single record exceeds in the case of excel 65528 bytes. Most likely there might be a similar limitation in other tools: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/record-size-exceeds-internal-limit-65535-bytes

As seen in the IBM help article a potential solution might be to check if there are any columns with particularly long text fields.

I already tried to narrow down the columns which might cause the issue by extracting the table sizes using DAX studio, however, did not find a particular culprit as the size of the columns caused by the number of lines/records does not relate to the size limitation on one record causing the issue in excel. As reference, the largest column in our dataset is the date field in the date table, which according to DAX studio is 10028.046875 KB large, but removing it only decreases the size of the record issue in excel by 40 byte from 92929 byte to 92889 byte.
In case you want to check the same on your dataset:
https://exceleratorbi.com.au/table-size-from-power-bi-desktop/

Hence in our case large record size is likely not caused by one particular column but the extensive amount of columns.
As found out with trial and error, the size limitation is affected by all tables available in the dataset even if some might be not connected via relationships.
Interim solution will be to use a subset/perspective of the dataset for excel analysis purposes.

Overall steps to narrow down a solution in your case:

- check for large columns and potentially remove them
- keep your dataset as lean as possible, remove unnecessary / unneeded columns
- work with part of the dataset for excel analysis purposes which only includes the data needed in excel

**->** all of these steps will help you to decrease your overall record size until you are below the size limit

Appreciate if someone found and could share a better solution to this issue which does not require the dataset to be reduced in size. This is the best solution I am so far able to come up with.

Related posts to this issue:

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/Analyze-in-Excel-Memory-Error/m-p/1447703

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/238947/azure-analysis-services-and-excel-maximum-page-siz.html